# Dynamic memory allocation with default values

Tags: c++

```
class A
{
private:
int m_nValue;
public:
A()
{
m_nValue = 0;
}
A(int nValue)
{
m_nValue = nValue);
~A()
{}
}
```

Now in main if i call

```
A a(2);// 2 will be assigned for m_nValue of object A.
```

Now how do we do this if i want to define an array of objects.
Also how do we do this if i dynamically create objects using operator new
like

```
A *pA;
pA = new A[5];// while creating the object i want the parameterised constructor to be 

//called
```

I hope the question is clear. Do let me know if more explanation is needed

Comment: More "curiosity"? Or more not being prepared to read a c++ textbook?

Comment: So which C++ textbook are you using in which this issue is not covered?

Comment: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this.

If you want to dynamically allocate an array, it has to be a default-constructable object. This means, it needs to have a constructor with no parameters, which is the one that will be used.

Comment: Not true. It would be true for arrays allocated with new-expressions, but not for arrays in general. An array of non-default-constructible objects can easily be declared with aggregate initializer.

Answer (score 2):

> if i want to define an array of objects

This is C++, you don't want arrays ;-)

```
std::vector<A> v(5, A(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You normally can't do this, as array objects are default constructed, but one quick hack is you can create a subclass whose default constructor passes on the parameter(s) you want to the base class.

```
template<int I>
class B : public A
{
public:
     B() : A(I) { }
};
...

A *pA;
pA = new B<42>[5];
```

Abusing inheritance in such a fashion is frowned upon in some circles, however.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define an array, you can use the aggregate initializer

```
A a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Note though that aggregate initialization follows copy-initialization semantics, so for each element it will be equivalent to

```
A a1 = 1;
```

not to your original

```
A a1(1);
```

As for the new-expression... The only initializer you can supply in the array new-expression is the empty `()` initializer, which triggers value-initialization. No other initializers are supported by the language at this time.