# C++ dynamic array

Tags: c++

I would like to make a dynamic array of a class with a constructor that has paramaters.

Where does the constructor's size parameter go?

ex. twoDArrayInDisguise = new dynamicArray(size)*[size];

Does not work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016772/dynamic-memory-allocation-with-default-values This is similar question

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do this directly (when using `new[]`, the default constructor is used).

Instead, use a `std::vector`.  You can initialise each element in terms of a reference object, e.g.:

```
std::vector<T> vec(size, T(/* args */));
```

Comment: +1 Also, this is the reason why T should support copy constructor and copy assignment if you intend to use it with a std::vector (or any other std container).

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you cannot dynamically create an array of a class with a constructor that has paramaters!